# fetch() URL won't get recognized

Tags: javascript, python, django

I keep getting error that the `get-response` in `fetch("/get-response/"` isn't found

> POST http://localhost/get-response/ 404 (Not Found)

Can you help me figure out why?
Here is some code

```
fetch("/get-response/", {  //<---- Not found
                body: JSON.stringify({'message': message['text']}),
                cache: 'no-cache', 
                credentials: 'same-origin', 
                headers: {
                    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors', 
                redirect: 'follow',
                referrer: 'no-referrer',
                })
```

The `get-response` is coming from urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.urls import path
from MyApp.views import Index, get_response
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('', Index),
    path('get-response/', get_response),
]
```

And the `get_response` is coming from views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_response(request):
    response = {'status': None}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        message = data['message']

        chat_response = chatbot.get_response(message).text
        response['message'] = {'text': chat_response, 'user': False, 'chat_bot': True}
        response['status'] = 'ok'

    else:
        response['error'] = 'no post data found'
```

Comment: are you hosting your python endpoint ?

Comment: @SunilLama I'm not really sure what endpoint is. Im using XAMPP to host it on localhost

Comment: yeap, you will have to use that. for example, if your hosting in localhost:3000 then in fetch, it should be `fetch("localhost:3000/get-response/")`

Comment: @SunilLama The error message that I get is **POST http://localhost/get-response/ 404 (Not Found)** I don't have a number after the localhost, do I need to have that?

Comment: normally your application should have been hosted in a port...maybe you can look into your xampp to see at which port it is running

Comment: @SunilLama It's using Main port 80 and SSL Port 443 but this isn't displayed in the localhost url for some reason.

Comment: that is because you don't have to show port for those, you first need to confirm the right path to get the data then use that on the frontend, basically your issue is you need to research on how to get the data in url first

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will look more into it